# How to read User Field Definitions with MPXJ

Tags: mpxj

I'm using MPXJ to read projects from both Primavera and MSP and would like to read the user field definition information e.g. the field label / description, any ideas how this can be achieved ?

Answer (score 0):

The detail you are looking for can be found by calling the `getCustomFields` method of a `ProjectFile` instance. You can either iterate through the contents of the container this method returns to see the configuration for all fields:

```
  for (CustomField field : projectFile.getCustomFields())
  {
     System.out.println("Field: " + field.getFieldType() + 
        " Alias: " + field.getAlias());
  }
```

or you can call `getCustomField` and pass a `FieldType` instance to look for the configuration of a specific field, for example:

```
projectFile.getCustomFields().getCustomField(TaskField.TEXT1)
```